# How can I do to highlight three specific dates?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, datepicker

I am trying to highlight three specific dates : "10-11-2020","22-11-2020", "07-11-2020" using React.js and Datepicker but I don't achieve to do this. Here is my code :

```
import React, {useState, Component} from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const Datepicker = (props) => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
 
  return (
    <DatePicker
      className="custom-select"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      selected={startDate}
      highlightDates={["10-11-2020","22-11-2020", "07-11-2020"]}
    />
  );
};

export default Datepicker;
```

I put my code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wescoff-mfpgj?file=/src/App.js

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass javascript date object array to `highlightDates`

```
<DatePicker
    .....
    highlightDates={[new Date("2020-11-15"), new Date("2020-11-20")]} //This should be js date array
/>
```

[Updated demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-gould-lx8u2)